# Get the string from the given string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want get the string value after the '\' from this NSString

```
   NSString *text = @"\"jkhfjkhfds" ;
```

How can I do it??

Comment: The \ is used to escape the `"` why do you want to remove it?

Comment: For example with `substringFromIndex` or `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet`

Comment: There is no `\ `  in the `NSString` value, only in the literal used to form it. The value of the `NSString` Produced by the literal is `"jkhfjkhfds`. What exactly do you need to do? What methods from `NSString` and/or `NSRegularExpression` have you tried, and what did not work in your attempted solutions? Edit your question to provide details and someone will undoubtedly help you. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@madhev  try this..

```
NSString *text = @"\"jkhfjkhfds";
    NSArray *arrSeparate = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""];
    NSLog(@"result = %@",[arrSeparate objectAtIndex:1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *text = @"\"jkhfjkhfds" ;  
text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];  
text= [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];  
NSLOg( NSLog(@"result = %@",text)`;`
```